# Getting database names, usernames via query for multi database instance/database server(s) - results showing in separate tables,

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, export-to-csv

I've got a small issue I'm not seeing the solution for. I'm running a combined query for the database instance name, database name and users in that database.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'

use db1
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];  
 
select name as username,
       create_date,
       modify_date,
       type_desc       
from sys.database_principals
where type not in ('A', 'G', 'R', 'X')
      and sid is not null
      and name != 'guest'
order by username;

SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'


use db2
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];  
 
select name as username,
       create_date,
       modify_date,
       type_desc       
from sys.database_principals
where type not in ('A', 'G', 'R', 'X')
      and sid is not null
      and name != 'guest'
order by username;

SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'


use etc
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];  
 
select name as username,
       create_date,
       modify_date,
       type_desc       
from sys.database_principals
where type not in ('A', 'G', 'R', 'X')
      and sid is not null
      and name != 'guest'
order by username;
```

The issue with the output is that its not usable even though its correct. (I'm trying to manually copy paste this into a text file).

My goal would be to get the output of this query into a CSV or other filetype.

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Why isn't the data useable? What's wrong with it? You title talks about having separate tables, but you have 8 queries there, so why would you *not* expect 8 result sets?

Comment: Hi Lamy ty for taking the time to look at my question. maybe my question should be how can i get all my output neatly into 1 csv

Comment: "Lamy"? With respect, you don't know me enough to give me a affectionate(?) nickname.

Comment: The datasets you have aren't all the same, 5 have a single column (and row) where as the others 4 columns and many rows. We would be better off trying to understanding the final result set you want. Why isn't Server Name and Database name a column in the data instead?

Comment: Sorry Larnu that was a typo My Goal is to get an overview of users (sql/windows) per database for my SQL server/instances in a CSV file

Comment: There's still no "m" in my alias. ;)

Comment: Is this meant to be against every database on the instance, or just the one's you have outlined above?

Comment: this query is compiled of parts i found on the web, that is why its likely not optimized for this goal

Comment: Yes this should be for every database on all the instances on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yu want to do this against each database, I'm going to use some (shameless) self promotion, and use a Procedure I created a called `sp_foreachdatabase`: [A CURSOR free version of sp_msforeachdb](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/). There *is* a built in procedure that does something similar, however, it is undocumented, and sometimes misbehaves. It also uses Cursors, which many of those experienced with SQL Server know to avoid as much as possible.

Once the above is created, I then change your query a little to put the server and database into columns instead, and then use the Pre and Post Command parameters to `CREATE` and `SELECT` from a temporary table I `INSERT` to data into.

This gives the following statement, after you have created the objects:

```sql
USE master;
GO

DECLARE @Command nvarchar(MAX) = N'INSERT INTO #Users (servername, databasename, username, create_date, modify_date, type_desc)
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS servername,
       & as databasename,
       [name] as username,
       create_date,
       modify_date,
       type_desc       
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE type NOT IN (''A'', ''G'', ''R'', ''X'')
  AND sid IS NOT NULL
  AND name != ''guest''
ORDER BY username;',
       @Pre_Command nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE TABLE #Users (servername sysname, databasename sysname, username sysname, create_date datetime, modify_date datetime, type_desc nvarchar(60));',
       @Post_Command nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM #Users;',
       @Command_Run nvarchar(MAX);

EXEC sp_foreachdatabase @Command = @Command,
                        @Skip_System = 1,
                        @Auto_Use = 1,
                        @Pre_Command = @Pre_Command,
                        @Post_Command = @Post_Command,
                        @Command_Run = @Command_Run OUTPUT;
--PRINT @Command_Run;
--SELECT @Command_Run;
```

Comment: I tip my hat to you sir, thank you very much for your time, i now have the information i am  looking for neatly in a table.